# tag collision in rocketmq

Tags: filter, tags, rocketmq

RocketMQ supports filter by tag, where I dig into the source code of the Broker. It seems the broker do the following comparison:
`subscriptionData.getCodeSet().contains(tagsCode.intValue());` in `org.apache.rocketmq.broker.filter.ExpressionMessageFilter#isMatchedByConsumeQueue`.
So i wonder if there is any chance two tags has the same hash code, and if that happens, some msg will not be filtered? I can't find any code comparing the actual tag String in Broker, am i missing something?

P.S.: my RocketMQ version is: 4.2.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT

Answer (score 0):

The hashcode of an int is itself ([source](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java)), so the hashcode of `tagsCode.intValue()` is itself. So as long as each code has a unique int value in the first place, there will be no hashcode collision.